# Is it possible to pass a variable as parameter of a POST variable? What is the syntax?

Tags: php, variables, post, syntax, parameter-passing

> **What would be the syntax for "`$dish[$i][$j]=$_post[$ds];`"  ?
> it's returning error "Undefined variable: _post in C:\wamp64\www\pizzeria\checkout.php on line 18"**

```
<?php

$ftable="SELECT * FROM dish Group By DishType";
            $ftableq=mysqli_query($con,$ftable); 
            if(isset($ftableq)){
            while($frows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ftableq))
            {$i=1;
              $dt=$frows['DishType'];
              $dtable="SELECT * FROM dish where DishType='$dt'";
            $dtableq=mysqli_query($con,$dtable); 
            if(isset($dtableq)){
            while($drows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($dtableq))
            {$j=1;
                $ds=$drows['DishName'];
                echo $ds;
                $dish[$i][$j]=$_post[$ds];
               
                ?>
                <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                    
                    <label><?php echo $dish[$i][$j];?></label>
                    
                    </form>
                </body>
                </html>
                <?php 
                $j=$j+1;
            }}
            $i=$i+1;
        }}
?>
```

Comment: It would normally be `$_POST`

Comment: without any brackets? Right?

Comment: As it's an array it would be `$_POST[$ds]`

Comment: If you `print_r($_POST);` you should see that it contains.

Comment: Yes, that is the concept I'm using. But the problem is, it is showing syntax error.

Comment: It would help if you show the error and indicate which line it's indicating.

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm having problem with line 18. "$dish[$i][$j]=$_post[$ds];"
and the error is "Undefined variable: _post in C:\wamp64\www\pizzeria\checkout.php on line 18"

which means I'm missing some syntax.

Comment: As it should be capitals (as I showed in my first comment).

Comment: Not working. I've already tried that.

Comment: Whatever it is you are trying to do here you are generating invalid HTML. It appears that you are generating the entire HTML content in a loop - so potentially there would be many entire HTML pages being generated in this single script. Also, assuming that you are using `$_POST` variables then your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. The multiple `nested queries` are not needed - this could be done in a single query

Comment: $_POST["$ds"] is working. Thank you.

Comment: @ Professor Abronsius Sir I know that it could be done but this is not complete code it's just for understanding purposes, I'm using different functions with every data that's why I'm using it in this way

 and the HTML portion is for your understanding this is not the actual code.

Comment: The main problem I was facing that the texts in the variables had spaces in them. There should not be any space in the parameter of a Post variable. So, I trimmed and replaced the spaces with function 'str_replace();' all the issues were solved. Thanks again.